# Using pre-minimised files

Tags: brunch

With Brunch is it possible during production build not to minimize certain js files (may be they are already minimised, or else) whilst still packing theses files along with the others ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible. Quoting the docs of `uglify-js-brunch`,

> Joined files can be ignored and be passed-through, using 'ignored' option:
>
> ```
> config =
>   plugins:
>     uglify:
>       ignored: /non_minimize\.js/
> ```
>
> (*https://github.com/brunch/uglify-js-brunch*)

The only requirement is that `ignored` be a regexp, so, for example, if you wanted to ignore several files, e.g. `vendor/a.js` and `vendor/b.js`, you'd go about it like this:

```
ignored: /^venodor\/a\.js|^vendor\/b\.js/
```

(You have to escape `/` to treat it as a slash because otherwise it'd be the regexp literal bounds marker, and `.` to interpret it as a dot and not a placeholder for any one character.)